# Javascript method chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, method-chaining

I have been trying to find a way to chain these methods together in a similar way to jQuery. here is an example of what I mean:

```
(function() {
    window.foo = function foo( id ) {
        if( window == this )
            return new foo( document.getElementById( id ) );

        this.alert = function() {
            alert( object.value ); 
        }
    }
}());

foo('input').alert();
```

So as you can see, I would like to use the object that was passed into the class as part of the alert function, but I do not want to store it in the class via `this.object = id`, and then do `alert( this.object.value );`

What would be an elegant way to go about this?

Comment: maybe you should read this : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery only chains by returning the same jQuery object from many of its methods. Your method doesn't always return a value, so it won't chain reliably. If you always have it return a value of the same type, chaining may begin to make sense.

```
window.foo = function foo( id ) {
    if( window === this )
        return new foo( document.getElementById( id ) );
    this.alert = function() {
        if (this.value) alert( this.value ); 
    }
    return this;
}

foo('input').alert();
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to store a reference in the object, because you already have it as `id`.

```
this.alert = function() {
    alert(id.value);
    return this;
}
```